# #Name? error while using ConvertCurrencyToEnglish function in access report

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007

im using below function for converting amount into words

```vb
Function ConvertCurrencyToEnglish(ByVal MyNumber)
  Dim Temp
         Dim Rupees, Paise
         Dim DecimalPlace, Count

         ReDim Place(9) As String
         Place(2) = " Thousand "
         Place(3) = " lakh "
         Place(4) = " Crore "     

         ' Convert MyNumber to a string, trimming extra spaces.
         MyNumber = Trim(Str(MyNumber))

         ' Find decimal place.
         DecimalPlace = InStr(MyNumber, ".")

         ' If we find decimal place...
         If DecimalPlace > 0 Then
            ' Convert Paise
            Temp = Left(Mid(MyNumber, DecimalPlace + 1) & "00", 2)
            ' Hi! Note the above line Mid function it gives right portion
            ' after the decimal point
            'if only . and no numbers such as 789. accures, mid returns nothing
            ' to avoid error we added 00
            ' Left function gives only left portion of the string with specified places here 2

            Paise = ConvertTens(Temp)

            ' Strip off paise from remainder to convert.
            MyNumber = Trim(Left(MyNumber, DecimalPlace - 1))
         End If

         Count = 1
        If MyNumber <> "" Then

            ' Convert last 3 digits of MyNumber to Indian Rupees.
            Temp = ConvertHundreds(Right(MyNumber, 3))

            If Temp <> "" Then Rupees = Temp & Place(Count) & Rupees

            If Len(MyNumber) > 3 Then
               ' Remove last 3 converted digits from MyNumber.
               MyNumber = Left(MyNumber, Len(MyNumber) - 3)
            Else
               MyNumber = ""
            End If
        End If

            ' convert last two digits to of mynumber
            Count = 2

            Do While MyNumber <> ""
            Temp = ConvertTens(Right("0" & MyNumber, 2))

            If Temp <> "" Then Rupees = Temp & Place(Count) & Rupees
            If Len(MyNumber) > 2 Then
               ' Remove last 2 converted digits from MyNumber.
               MyNumber = Left(MyNumber, Len(MyNumber) - 2)

            Else
               MyNumber = ""
            End If
            Count = Count + 1

            Loop

         ' Clean up rupees.
         Select Case Rupees
            Case ""
               Rupees = ""
            Case "One"
               Rupees = "One Rupee"
            Case Else
               Rupees = Rupees & " Rupees"
         End Select

         ' Clean up paise.
         Select Case Paise
            Case ""
               Paise = ""
            Case "One"
               Paise = "One Paise"
            Case Else
               Paise = Paise & " Paise"
         End Select

         If Rupees = "" Then
         ConvertCurrencyToEnglish = Paise
         ElseIf Paise = "" Then
         ConvertCurrencyToEnglish = Rupees
         Else
         ConvertCurrencyToEnglish = Rupees & " and " & Paise
         End If

End Function

Private Function ConvertDigit(ByVal MyDigit)
        Select Case Val(MyDigit)
            Case 1: ConvertDigit = "One"
            Case 2: ConvertDigit = "Two"
            Case 3: ConvertDigit = "Three"
            Case 4: ConvertDigit = "Four"
            Case 5: ConvertDigit = "Five"
            Case 6: ConvertDigit = "Six"
            Case 7: ConvertDigit = "Seven"
            Case 8: ConvertDigit = "Eight"
            Case 9: ConvertDigit = "Nine"
            Case Else: ConvertDigit = ""
         End Select
End Function

Private Function ConvertHundreds(ByVal MyNumber)
    Dim Result As String

         ' Exit if there is nothing to convert.
         If Val(MyNumber) = 0 Then Exit Function

         ' Append leading zeros to number.
         MyNumber = Right("000" & MyNumber, 3)

         ' Do we have a hundreds place digit to convert?
         If Left(MyNumber, 1) <> "0" Then
            Result = ConvertDigit(Left(MyNumber, 1)) & " Hundred "
         End If

         ' Do we have a tens place digit to convert?
         If Mid(MyNumber, 2, 1) <> "0" Then
            Result = Result & ConvertTens(Mid(MyNumber, 2))
         Else
            ' If not, then convert the ones place digit.
            Result = Result & ConvertDigit(Mid(MyNumber, 3))
         End If

         ConvertHundreds = Trim(Result)
End Function

Private Function ConvertTens(ByVal MyTens)
          Dim Result As String

         ' Is value between 10 and 19?
         If Val(Left(MyTens, 1)) = 1 Then
            Select Case Val(MyTens)
               Case 10: Result = "Ten"
               Case 11: Result = "Eleven"
               Case 12: Result = "Twelve"
               Case 13: Result = "Thirteen"
               Case 14: Result = "Fourteen"
               Case 15: Result = "Fifteen"
               Case 16: Result = "Sixteen"
               Case 17: Result = "Seventeen"
               Case 18: Result = "Eighteen"
               Case 19: Result = "Nineteen"
               Case Else
            End Select
         Else
            ' .. otherwise it's between 20 and 99.
            Select Case Val(Left(MyTens, 1))
               Case 2: Result = "Twenty "
               Case 3: Result = "Thirty "
               Case 4: Result = "Forty "
               Case 5: Result = "Fifty "
               Case 6: Result = "Sixty "
               Case 7: Result = "Seventy "
               Case 8: Result = "Eighty "
               Case 9: Result = "Ninety "
               Case Else
            End Select

            ' Convert ones place digit.
            Result = Result & ConvertDigit(Right(MyTens, 1))
         End If

         ConvertTens = Result
End Function
```

but repeatedly im getting a #Name? error

Pls help me out of this

Comment: The quality of this post would be improved by shortening it. This way you are more likely to get the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I maybe late answering your question. Did you use Access 2016?

I also faced the same problem when copy my system from Access 2010 to Access 2016. Then, I copy these file : mscomct2.ocx and mscomct2 in: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office16\" on the machine running Access 2016.

Maybe here can help u to find the files.

https://www.ocxme.com/files/mscomct2_ocx

Hope this will help you..